# Bringing a joptionpane infront of all other windows

Tags: java, joptionpane

The concept is simple. I'd like to bring a JOptionPane frame in front of **all** other currently open windows/applications.

I'd like to do this *without* the help of anything like applescript (external java) or any third party library. Pure java.

I have searched for this all over but couldn't find one single non-third party solution. (.toFront() simply "focuses" on the window but doesn't actually display it in the front.)

The JOptionPanel and JDialog code:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(p4.msg, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Important1!");
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Where p4 is an object containing a public string.

Comment: You don't mean modal yes? For `JDialog` another call to `setVisible(true)` normally works, so this could help here as well.

Comment: I have never messed around with "modal" and since I'm swiss I really can't make any sense of it. Could you explain? @tomse Google didn't help me so far

Comment: If I understand you right your `JOptionPane` is opened already when you want to bring it to front? Opening a dialog _modal_ means that all other dialogs will be blocked for input if the _modal_ dialog is opened. See [Dialog.setModal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29).

Comment: Yes, the joptionpane is already open at that time. however, that doesnt bring it in front of all other windows, right? @tomse

Comment: Have you tried `setVisible(true)` instead of calling `toFront()`?

Comment: Can you show us some code? How the `JOptionPane` works is dependent on how you create it.

Comment: are you passing the parent component to it when creating it, or passing a null.  showing some of the code that you written could help

Comment: @faljbour and others, I have now added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am assuming you are calling the JOptionPane from a frame, so pass the frame reference by using this, It should show it on top of at least your running program assuming it has focus.

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, p4.msg,"Important1!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```